# Finding integer solutions to complex numbers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers

> Prove that if $n$ is an integer and $n > 2$, then $\bar z=z^{n-1}$ has $n+1$  solutions.

I tried multiplying the equation by the conjugate, but I only get $n$ solutions, not $n+1$. The same thing happened when I tried to multiply both sides of the equation by $z$ to get $z^n=\mod(z^2)$

Comment: I did not know that..Thank you

Comment: $0$ is one solution. Multiply both sides by $z$ get $|z|^2=z^n$ which has $n$ non-zero solutions (related to roots of unity), total $n+1$